# Reloading View on dismissViewController (Modal)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to reload a graph with datapoints after one has been deleted from a tableview. I call the

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

to get the modal off of the page, but then the viewWillAppear method of the root viewcontroller does not get called.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your code to refresh the graph in the `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the setup of your app? My understanding is that you have a graph view that is presenting a modal view that allows the user to edit points? Or are they within the same view?

Comment: @TerryG How can you leave a comment of "Tried, did not work." and mark the answer as accepted...?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I forgot to come back and say why it worked. Ultimately I had forgotten to refresh the graph view completely. I recalculated the data but forgot the final line to refresh. So this answer was technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass `nil` to the `completion:` argument.  You can instead pass it a block of code to execute.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        // code to execute upon completion
    }];
```

As a note, you really shouldn't be calling `viewWillAppear:`.  Instead, you should put your logic for reloading your graph in its own method.  In `viewWillAppear:`, call that method, and then in the completion block, also call that method.  We shouldn't need to re-execute EVERYTHING in `viewWillAppear:`, as most of your view controller's view is already set up (it wasn't deallocated).  All we need to do is reload one part of the screen.